# New Badge Idea - StackEVERYTHING

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request

Will there ever be a badge for OCD or Stack Exchange addicts who are subscribed to all Stack Exchange Networks / Subdomains?

Also, there are other badge ideas floating around on Meta, could there ever be an official poll/post/other?

That would be kind of funny. *Yes, I am one of those people* ;-)

Stack Exchange EVERYTHING are great resources. I'd assume, it's a cheap badge to receive for many, but may show true dedication, commitment, and interest for others.

Comment: Given that there is a tag [badge-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badge-request), I doubt there will be a single poll-like question for that.

Comment: What if a new SE site comes which the user isn't subscribed to? Would the badge still be valid? Sorry no, this badge doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Oh, cool. That makes sense. Thanks for adding that and letting me know.

Comment: Good question @Chichiray

Comment: Wow, people on Meta are vicious with downvotes huh. Too bad I don't even know what is wrong with the question other than what Arjan and Chichiray commented.

Comment: Votes on meta sites mean disagreement with a feature request, or with what implied in the question.

Comment: @TryTryAgain: Downvotes on Meta basically indicate disagreement. Badges are meant to encourage good behaviour - merely signing up on all the Stack Exchange sites doesn't show any level of *involvement* - I can't see how it counts as behaviour we want to encourage.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I thought it was more a place for discussions about questions.

Comment: So I got banned from asking questions because I asked this?!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would almost certainly lead to a bunch of users making accounts on other sites for no other reason than to have an account and try to farm the badge.

There is a *wide* range of topics covered by Stack Exchange sites, and that range grows all the time.  The chances of having users who *truly* cross that entire domain are very, very small.  Understanding that 90% of all statistics are made up on the spot, I'd argue that well over 99% of the people with this badge won't actually use all of the Stack Exchange sites and, instead, just pollute those sites with an unnecessary user account just to get the badge.

One might take it a step further and say, "Fine, then you need to at least *participate* in the other sites in order to qualify for the badge."  Except that this won't change the demographic of people who try to acquire the badge.  It will only persuade them to post low quality content on sites in which they aren't actually interested.

In short, I just don't see this as encouraging or rewarding the kind of behavior Stack Exchange wants.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to lay that out. I completely agree. With this answer and the comments above, I feel silly asking the question in the first place, but it was almost jokingly asked: "That would be kind of funny." Thanks, again.